# Overlayed Diagrams with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I am looking for an efficient way to my a diagram like the one below with TikZ. I have looked in the manual and searched for other questions but could not find something that helped me.
Any help on this topic is very welcome. Thanks everyone.

[image]

Comment: and what you try so far?

Comment: so far I used the `\draw` command to do the rectangles. But they get overlayed in the wrong order and I do not know how to change the position of the text inside.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of you've tried so far.

Comment: 1. You could define different boxes(block1, block2,...) with `\tikzset{block/.style={
      rectangle,
      draw=blue!100,
      fill=blue!70,
      rounded corners=15pt,
      minimum height=10em,
      minimum width=20em,
      ...
    }}` 2. Positioning with `\node[block] (A) at (0,0)  {};` 3. Text inside: `\node[below] at (A.north) {Real};` . Related links-> An example for defining a box you can find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8906/124842) and for tikzset [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312779/124842).

Comment: Tikz draws in the order you give the commands, i.e. back to front. If you have a simple overlap problem, just re-arrange your code to reflect the levels. That is, `\draw first level`, `\draw second level` and so on.

Answer (score 11):

My audacious mathematical theory about [Euler diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram)
seem to have failed to convince in the comments, so I revert back.

*(and my code did not compile due to a linebreak)*

Anyway, I borrow some of the techniques demo'd by @CarLaTeX [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375484/116936).  Props to her !

#### Edits

- Fixed colors and fonts
- Added CSS-like padding syntax
- No more rules, added node for title positioning

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{myCyan}{HTML}{479FF8}
\definecolor{myRed}{HTML}{DB3D24}
\definecolor{myGreen}{HTML}{81D552}
\definecolor{myOrange}{HTML}{EFBD3F}
\tikzset
{
  pics/maBoite/.style args={#1/#2/#3/#4/#5/#6}%
  {
    code=
    {
      \def\myPaddingArray{{#5,#5,#5,#5}}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\paddingTop}{\myPaddingArray[0]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\paddingRight}{\myPaddingArray[1]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\paddingBottom}{\myPaddingArray[2]}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\paddingLeft}{\myPaddingArray[3]}
      \path {[name prefix ..](#1)} -- ++(\paddingLeft pt,\paddingBottom pt) coordinate (-belowLeft);
      \path {[name prefix ..](#2)} -- ++(-\paddingRight pt,-\paddingTop pt) coordinate (-topRight);
      \fill [rounded corners=.4cm, #3] (-belowLeft) rectangle (-topRight) ;
      \makeatletter
        \path (-belowLeft) |- (-topRight) coordinate[pos=.75] (-titleT@pTmp);
        \path (-titleT@pTmp) -- ++(0,-4.5mm) coordinate (-titleTop);
      \makeatother
      \path (-belowLeft) -- (-topRight) coordinate[pos=.5] (-titleMiddle);
      \node at #6 [white, font=\large, inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=2.5mm] {\textbf{#4}} ;
    }
  },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=7cm,y=4cm]
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (b) at (1,1);
  \coordinate (mt) at (.5,1);
  \coordinate (mb) at (.5,0);
  % syntax
  % \pic 
  % { 
  %   maBoite=
  %   {
  %     <lowerLeft>/<upperRight>/<color>/%
  %     <title>/<CSS-syntax padding>/<title-position>
  %   }
  % }; 
  \def\myTopPadding{.85cm}
  \def\myBottomPadding{.15cm}
  \def\mySidePadding{.15cm}
  \pic (R) {maBoite={a/b/myCyan/Reals/0/(-titleTop)}}; 
  \pic (Q) {maBoite={R-belowLeft/mt/myRed/Rationals/\myTopPadding,.07cm,\myBottomPadding,.2cm/(-titleTop)}}; 
  \pic (Z) {maBoite={Q-belowLeft/Q-topRight/myGreen/Integers/\myTopPadding,\mySidePadding,\myBottomPadding,\mySidePadding/(-titleTop)}}; 
  \pic (N) {maBoite={Z-belowLeft/Z-topRight/myCyan/Naturals/\myTopPadding,\mySidePadding,\myBottomPadding,\mySidePadding/(-titleMiddle)}}; 
  \pic (I) {maBoite={mb/R-topRight/myOrange/Irrationals/\myTopPadding,.2cm,\myBottomPadding,.07cm/(-titleMiddle)}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You did well to ping me in a comment under my answer because it doesn't work in an answer body. OMG, I have a follower, LOL! +1, your `pic`s are perfect for me, but I'm a beginner! I'd like to answer here, too, using `fit`.

Comment: ... but Ignasi was faster than me, LOL!

Comment: Yes, the blue part represents the algebraic irrationals, but “Reals” should go outside.

Comment: @egreg I think what I drew is coherent : the green area **integers** is to be understood as containing the **naturals**, even though those are not filled in green. The same goes for **reals**.

Comment: @marsupilam Imho it looks wrong (not your fault as the starting image in itself is problematic). Where e.g. would you place \sqrt{2}? And where \pi?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, I don't see what you mean : `sqrt(2)` is a real that is neither rational nor non-algebraic `=>` **blue zone**. `pi` is a real that is non-algebraic `=>` **orange zone**.

Comment: But the blue zone is *around* the  rationals. So following your own argument above "10" is a natural, an integer, a rational *and* a "neither rational nor non-algebraic" number.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry if I'm being dense, but I think this is what a mathematically sound [Euler diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram) of those sets looks like when *we fill without using transparency* (the layers are even correct in the pdf file).

Comment: The irrational numbers are all the numbers that are not rational. So rational/irrational splits the real number in two disctinct, non overlaping parts, which fills up the reals. Your image doesn't convey this idea. Replace "rational" by mammals, and "irrational" by non-mammals and "real" by animals.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I understand your point about rationals and irrationals, you are right. But the purpose of the post is just about TikZ!

But thanks to everyone that helped with the code examples. This was very helpful!

Answer (score 8):

Another solution with nodes placed on a `matrix` (you could also use `positioning` library) and color boxes drawn as `fit` nodes on a `background` layer.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, backgrounds, fit}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mytext/.style={text=white, font=\sffamily\large}]

\matrix (N) [ 
    matrix of nodes,  
    nodes={mytext, anchor=center, rounded corners},     
    label={[name=name, mytext]Reals},
    column sep=3mm,
    row sep= 0mm,]{
        Rationals & \\
        Integers & Irrationals \\
        |[fill=cyan]|Naturals \\
    };

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[fit={(N) (name)}, fill=cyan, rounded corners] {};

\node[fit=(N-1-1) (N-3-1), fill=red, rounded corners] (aux) {};

\node[fit=(N-2-1) (N-3-1), inner ysep=1pt, fill=green, rounded corners] {};

\node[fit=(aux), inner sep=0pt, anchor=center, fill=orange, rounded corners] at (N-2-2){};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]